# Execute custom python script from Django models

Tags: python, django, execution

Trying to execute a python script from Django models and I receive the following error:

> ```
> File "D:\FL\Django\mysite\uploadfileapp\models.py", line 23, in get_absolute_url
>   Best_model_forecast_v11.main(user_avatar)
> NameError: name 'Best_model_forecast_v11' is not defined
> ```

The above script is located in same app directory with `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from uploadfileapp.Best_model_forecast_v11 import *
# Create your models here.
from django.urls import reverse

class User(models.Model):

    #the variable to take the inputs
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_avatar = models.FileField()

    # on submit click on the user entry page, it redirects to the url below.
    def get_absolute_url(self):

        Best_model_forecast_v11.main(user_avatar)
        return reverse('uploadfileapp:home')
```

Comment: You're importing everything from `Best_model_forecast_v11` into the current namespace. So you probably want to call `main(user_avatar)` instead. Hard to say without seeing an excerpt of that module though. Whatever the case - this does work. You're just not importing it correctly.

Comment: Ok. So how should I import it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: I'm flying blind without seeing the module - but I would assume something like `from uploadfileapp import Best_model_forecast_v11`

Answer (score 1):

you are incorrectly importing the file, change:

```
from uploadfileapp.Best_model_forecast_v11 import *
```

to;

```
from uploadfileapp.models.Best_model_forecast_v11 import *
```

Comment: I solved it calling as: main("some csv file") instead of Best_model_forecast_v11.main("some csv file"). The only problem I still face is that I have to pass the file location and name in clear into main function. If I try main(models.FileField()), it will not work.